# How to set connection charset using node-oracledb

Tags: node.js, oracle

I am trying to connect to Oracle database from node.js.

I have successfully installed the [node-oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb) driver.
I can connect to my Oracle database using the TNSNAMES file.

The problem is, my database is using NLS_CHARACTERSET EE8ISO8859P2 character set. 
In php applications I can change that to use UTF-8 while calling oci_pconnect.

Is there a way to do the same with node driver?

Comment: Long shot but what is your NLS_LANG environment variable set to?  You could try `export NLS_LANG=<NLS_LANGUAGE>_<NLS_TERRITORY>.EE8ISO8859P2` (replace the caretted parts as needed for your scenario) prior to running you Node app and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

From version 1.0, node-oracledb now always sets the "client" character set to Oracle's AL32UTF8 character set.  Not that this would help with your putty issue!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: I AM AN IDIOT!

Everything with Oracle and oracle driver is OK. 
I was using a replacement laptop and my putty was not set correctly. I was testing node oracle dirver with TRANSLATION option in putty set to ISO-8859-2 while the linux server was using UTF-8.

So the charset was malformed during the ssh transmision to my windows laptop :-(